# cronometro multihilo en python

Tags: python, python-2.x

estoy haciendo un proyecto para la escuela en el cual tengo que programar un software que ayude a los niños a mejorar su ortografía:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random  
import subprocess
def corrector(pbien, tup):
    if tup == pbien:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1
mw = ("mucica", "presio", "vanda", "kansiones","yenar","majia","chiko","embidia","cinfonia")
gw = ("musica","precio","banda","canciones", "llenar", "magia", "chico", "envidia", "sinfonia")
count = 0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wt = True
    while wt:
        subprocess.call(["cmd.exe","/c","cls"])
        randint = random.randint(0, len(mw) - 1)
        print('''corrige: {}
puntos: {}'''.format(mw[randint], count))
        yourw = str(raw_input("> "))
        check = corrector(gw[randint], yourw)
        count += check
        if count >= 5:
            wt = False
            print("ganaste")
        elif count <= -3:
            wt = False
            print("perdiste")
```

siento que el programa es muy simple, por lo que quiero agregar un cronometro para que sea un poco más desafiante, el cronometro iría antes de la variable 'yourw' y también tendría que haber un if algo así:

```
if cronometro < 0:
    wt = False
    print("perdiste, se te acabo el tiempo")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Actualización

> En realidad la versión con `select()` que se explica en esta respuesta sólo funciona en Unix, porque en Windows esta función sólo admite descriptores de sockets y no de ficheros (ni de la entrada estándar).
>
> Por tanto esta respuesta no es útil para el usuario que aparentemente trabaja en Windows. No obstante he decidido dejarla por si fuera útil a otros usuarios.
>
> Una solución que sí funciona en Windows aparece al final de la respuesta original, en el apartado **Solución en Windows**

## Respuesta original

No es necesario entrar en programación multihilo para hacer lo que pretendes. Se puede usar la función `select()`.

Esta función permite esperar en una lista de "objetos" por los que podrías recibir datos (pueden ser ficheros, sockets o, en tu caso, el teclado) hasta que o bien uno de esos objetos haya recibido datos, o bien se agote el tiempo de espera. En cualquiera de los dos casos `select()` termina su ejecución y te retorna una lista que contiene los objetos por los que se han recibido datos (si la lista está vacía es que no se recibió por ninguno, y por tanto que el tiempo de espera se agotó).

En tu caso, podrías pasarle a `select()` una lista con un único objeto: la entrada estándar (el teclado). Si a la vuelta de `select()` ese objeto está en la lista retornada, es que hay datos esperando ser leídos del teclado, y simplemente llamas a `raw_input()` para leerlos (el cual no se bloqueará esperando nada, porque ya hay algo). En caso contrario es que el tiempo se ha agotado.

La siguiente es una función que implementa estas ideas:

```py
def espera_respuesta(tiempo_max=5):
    print "> ",
    sys.stdout.flush()

    entrada = sys.stdin.fileno()
    listo, _ ,_ = select.select([entrada], [], [], tiempo_max)
    if entrada in listo:
        respuesta = raw_input()
        return respuesta
    else:
        return None
```

Las dos primeras líneas son para imprimir el "prompt" invitando al usuario a escribir algo. Después preparamos el objeto "entrada" y se lo pasamos a `select()` (esta función espera en realidad tres listas separadas, pero las otras dos no las usamos y se las paso vacías). El último parámetro es el tiempo máximo que select esperará.

`select()` retorna tres listas, de las cuales de nuevo sólo me interesa la priemera (las otras dos vendrán vacías). Si `entrada` está en la lista retornada, es que hay datos. Los leo. Si no, es que se agotó el tiempo. Retorno `None` para indicar que el usuario no escribió nada.

Desde tu programa usarías esta función así, por ejemplo:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wt = True
    while wt:
        cls()
        randint = random.randint(0, len(mw) - 1)
        print('corrige: {}\npuntos: {}'.format(mw[randint], count))
        yourw = espera_respuesta()
        if yourw is None:
            print("\n¡Tiempo agotado!")
            time.sleep(2)
            continue
        check = corrector(gw[randint], yourw)
        count += check
        if count >= 5:
            wt = False
            print("ganaste")
        elif count <= -3:
            wt = False
            print("perdiste")
```

Fíjate cómo en vez de tu anterior `raw_input()` ahora hay una llamada a `espera_respuesta()`. Cuando ésta retorna, si te devolvió `None`, imprimes un mensaje de tiempo agotado (pausamos el programa un par de segundos para que el usuario tenga tiempo de leerlo antes de que borres la pantalla de nuevo) y volvemos al inicio del bucle con `continue`. Observa que en este caso no penalizamos al jugador, pues no pasamos el corrector a su respuesta. Elimina el `continue` si quieres que se verifique la respuesta (y ya que ésta fue `None`, no será igual a lo esperado y se le penalizaría).

### Otra mejora

En lugar de almacenar la lista de palabras bien y mal en dos variables separadas, podrías tener un diccionario cuyas claves fueran las palabras mal y los valores la versión corregida. Creo que así es más sencillo añadir vocabulario al juego. La variable sería por ejemplo así:

```py
vocabulario = {
 'chiko': 'chico',
 'cinfonia': 'sinfonia',
 'embidia': 'envidia',
 'kansiones': 'canciones',
 'majia': 'magia',
 'mucica': 'musica',
 'presio': 'precio',
 'vanda': 'banda',
 'yenar': 'llenar'
}
```

Para elegir una al azar, puedes usar `random.choice(list(vocabulario))`. La expresión `list(vocabulario)` te convierte el diccionario en lista, quedándose sólo con las claves (las palabras mal), y `random.choice()` devuelve un elemento al azar de esa lista. Una vez tienes la palabra mal escrita, su versión buena sería `vocabulario[mal]`. Es decir:

```py
    mal = random.choice(list(vocabulario))
    bien = vocabulario[mal]
```

## Solución en Windows

En windows la solución con `select()` no es válida. Una solución multihilo también sería bastante compleja puesto que, aunque es fácil hacer que otro hilo espere un tiempo e imprima "Tiempo agotado", no es tan fácil interrumpir al hilo principal que estará todavía esperando en `raw_input()` a que el usuario introduzca algo.

Resulta más sencillo hacer una función que lea del teclado "tecla a tecla", en un bucle, cronometrando mientras lee, y dando por terminada la lectura si se agota el tiempo disponible.

Esta sería una posible implementación (específica de Windows pues hace uso del módulo `msvcrt`):

```py
import msvcrt
def espera_respuesta(tiempo_max=5):
    print "> ",
    sys.stdout.flush()

    horafinal = time.time() + tiempo_max
    resultado = []   # Iremos almacenando aqui las teclas pulsadas
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():           # Si hay tecla pulsada
            tecla = msvcrt.getche()  # la leemos
            if tecla == '\r':        # si es retorno de carro
                print()
                return ''.join(resultado)  # Retornamos la cadena leida
            resultado.append(tecla)  # Si no, metemos la tecla a la lista
        time.sleep(0.1)              # breve pausa para no saturar la CPU
        if time.time() > horafinal:  # Si se agotó el tiempo, volvemos
            return None
```